# Watir 4.0.2 Click crashes the browser

Tags: ruby, watir

The following code is causing some issues:

```ruby
b = Watir::Browser.new

options =  b.select.options

options.each do |opt|
  s =  opt.text
  i = s.length - 1
  if s[i-1] == '(' then
    puts s
    b.select().select_value(s)
    b.text_field(:id => 'nombre', :name => 'nombre').value = '0'
    b.input(:class => 'bouton-ajouter').click
  end
end
```

When the click is performed it stops doing the each and just crashes.
Why could this be so?

Comment: Is there a reason you have to use v4.0.2, which is almost 8 years old? There have been various fixes since then so it's possible it's already addressed.

Comment: Yes , dat's what they used at the company i work actually , they dont want to upgrade :(

Comment: That's unfortunate, hopefully you can change their mind. Is there any exception when the script runs? What browser and version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to do, but I have corrected your program a bit, try this

```
require 'watir'

b = Watir::Browser.new

b.select_list.options.each { |opt|
  s = opt.text
  if s.chars.last == '('
    puts s
    b.select_list.option(text: s).select
    b.text_field(:id => 'nombre', :name => 'nombre').set '0'
    b.input(:class => 'bouton-ajouter').click
  end
}
```

Comment: I dont really want to break the for each , I want to iterate on all option and if it match my condition , fill some value and press a button and noramlly it just refresh the page so I can go on to the next option

Comment: Oh okay. I removed the break, but as Justin pointed out, please try to move to the new version.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you guys for your help, I think I just figured out how to do it , I will just reload my browser go back to my select change another option and create a while on it until there's no option dat match my condition, is the easiest way I think ( if I cant upgrade).